# Get common and uncommon records from SQL tables

Tags: sql

I have tow tables named TableA and TableB

Let us say TableA

```
Id   TableAName 
------------------
 1     11
 2     12
 3     13
 4     14
 5     15
```

Let us say TableB

```
Id   TableBName 
----------------
 1     11
 2     22
 3     23
 4     24
 5     25
```

I want result like below

```
 TableAName  TableBName
-------------------------
   11           11
   12           Null
   13           Null 
   14           Null  
   15           Null
   Null         22
   Null         23
   Null         24
   Null         25
```

I am confuse to get this result. I need records , if both column has same value than display in one row , otherwise not.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard SQL:

```
SELECT
  A.TableAName, B.TableBName
FROM
  TableA A
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  TableB B ON A.TableAName = B.TableBName
```

MySQL does not support FULL OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT
  A.TableAName, B.TableBName
FROM
  TableA A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  TableB B ON A.TableAName = B.TableBName
UNION
SELECT
  A.TableAName, B.TableBName
FROM
  TableA A
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  TableB B ON A.TableAName = B.TableBName
```

Edit, taken from @Dems deleted answer

You can add this to get the same order as above

```
ORDER BY
     COALESCE(A.TableAName, B.TableAName)
```